# Wordpress Rest api querying empty object meta

Tags: wordpress, rest

I added a user custom meta field, registering it like this (WP > 5.3):

```
  register_meta('user', 'custom_avatar', array(
    'type' => 'object',
    'description' => 'custom avatar',
    'single' => true,
    'show_in_rest' => array(
      'schema' => array(
        'type' => 'object',
        'properties' => array(
          'id' => array(
            'type' => 'number'
          ),
          'url' => array(
            'type' => 'string'
          )
        )
      )
    )
  ));
```

When the field exists, the GET user request returns the corresponding object,

[image: GET user response with existing meta]

but when the field doesn't exist yet the GET request returns an empty array.

[image]

I was expecting an empty object... Did I do anything wrong or is it the normal wordpress behavior?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try to add user meta using `add_user_meta` or `update_user_meta`?

Comment: I don't think it will change the problem, those 2 functions are used to set or update a user meta value declaring the meta if required. register_meta is used to declare a meta field for a future use.